# SNMP - Where is "TimeStamp" Syntax defined?

Tags: syntax, timestamp, snmp

Where to import from the textual convention `TimeStamp` in SNMP MIB?

I have a MIB where I should add a timestamp, but I don't know where I can import its syntax from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an example MIB that uses TimeStamp, see

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4444#section-4

```
  IMPORTS
    TEXTUAL-CONVENTION, RowStatus, TruthValue, TimeStamp
            FROM SNMPv2-TC               -- RFC2579
```

It is defined in SNMPv2-TC, see

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2579

Comment: fyi errata exists -- year range 65536 won't work